# Inheritance resolution

Tags: c++, inheritance, overload-resolution

I thought that types would *automatically* resolve to the *deepest part of the hierarchy they could*.   If `Cat : Animal` and you call `cat->talk()`, if `Cat` overrides a `talk()` from class `Animal`, the cat will say "meow", not some weird general `Animal` grumbling provided in base class `Animal`.

So I'm confused about this:

```
struct Animal
{
  virtual void talkTo( Animal* o ) {
    puts( "Animal-Animal" ) ;
  }
} ;

struct Cat : public Animal
{
  virtual void talkTo( Animal* o ) {
    puts( "Cat-Animal" ) ;
  }
  virtual void talkTo( Cat* o ) {
    puts( "Cat says meow to Cat" ) ;
  }
} ;
```

Here's some calling code:

```
  Cat *cat = new Cat() ;
  cat->talkTo( cat ) ; //Cat says meow to Cat

  Animal *animalCatPtr = cat ;      
  cat->talkTo( animalCatPtr ) ; //Cat-Animal
```

The last line here, where I send a `Cat` to `cat->talkTo`, but I'm using `animalCatPtr`.  `animalCatPtr` still refers to a `Cat`, but yet its resolving to simply an `Animal` in the function call.

How can I make the *pass pointer resolve to the deepest type in the hierarchy it really is*?  I don't want to do a series of `dynamic_cast<>` testing to see if the `Animal` I have on hand is really a `Cat` or `Dog` or what have you.

Comment: Only the `void(Animal*)` member function is overridden. The other one is a *new* overload, only defined in `Cat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to use "double dispatch" to achieve this.  How crufty.

Basically, as the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) says,

> The problem is that, while virtual functions are dispatched dynamically in C++, function overloading is done statically.

So, what you have to do is modify `class Cat`:

```
struct Cat : public Animal
{
  virtual void talkTo( Animal* o ) {
    //puts( "Cat-Animal" ) ;
    o->talkTo( this ) ; // TURN THE INVOKATION AROUND ("double dispatch")
  }
  virtual void talkTo( Cat* o ) {
    puts( "Cat says meow to Cat" ) ;
  }
} ;
```

Now, in

```
cat->talkTo( animalCatPtr ) ;
```

`animalCatPtr` is *actually* a `Cat*`.  But the `talkTo` function doesn't know that, until we "turn around the invokation" in `Cat::talkTo( Animal* )`.

If `animalCatPtr` is actually only an `Animal`, then we will end up in base class `Animal`, invoking `Animal::talkTo( Cat* )` if that is available, or `Animal::talkTo( Animal* )` if only that function is available.

If `animalCatPtr` is actually a `Cat`, then we will end up invoking `Cat::talkTo( Cat* )`, which is the behavior we wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You want a form of double-dispatch, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Comment: So in other words, `dynamic_cast<>()`

Comment: @bobobobo - not at all, with dynamic dispatch you use a base pointer passed to your dynamic object to polymorphicly bridge to another member function.

Comment: Ok, I get it.  I [added more info in an answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987136/111307)